# RabbitMQ in NestJS, error on both Producer and Consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I have the following app https://github.com/rengthp/nestjs-rabbitmq-microservice

But I get  on Producer :

[Nest] 6156   - 04/03/2021, 13:28:53   [ClientProxy] Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect. +25469ms
[Nest] 6156   - 04/03/2021, 13:28:53   [ClientProxy] Object:

```
{
  "err": {
    "code": 406,
    "classId": 50,
    "methodId": 10
  }
}
 +3ms
```

and on Consumer:

```
111ms
[Nest] 1180   - 04/03/2021, 13:22:31   [Server] Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect. +1058ms
[Nest] 1180   - 04/03/2021, 13:22:37   [Server] Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect. +6006ms
[Nest] 1180   - 04/03/2021, 13:22:43   [Server] Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect. +6017ms
[Nest] 1180   - 04/03/2021, 13:22:49   [Server] Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect. +6026ms
```

What could be wrong? the server is working...

Comment: Hi @CarlosMagalhaes I'm facing the same issue, how did you solve it...?. I'm getting on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me changing the type of the RabbitMQ QUEUE I was using from transient to durable fixed it

Answer (score 2):

This error came up because you re-declare an existing queue with different parameters. The solution is simple. The option queue for both producers and consumers must be the same and all option parameters must be the same.

Answer (score 2):

try to left time to api gateway to connect rabbit,

in your controller, use **onApplicationBootstrap** function

`async onApplicationBootstrap() { await this._clientProxyUser.connect();}`

you can read more here [lifecycle events nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events)